# keinen Gedanken verwenden?

Tags: meaning

Ich kenne die Redewendung "keinen Gedanken **verschwenden** **an** etw." Vor einigen Tagen bin ich jedoch auf eine seltsame Variante(?) derselben gestoßen:

*keinen Gedanken **auf** etw. **verwenden***

Hier das Beispiel:

> Die Jugendlichen bekennen, **auf** Altersvorsorge **verwendeten** sie derzeit keinen Gedanken.

Hat diese Redewendung dieselbe Bedeutung?

Comment: Inwiefern ist die Bedeutung unklar? Welche verschiedenen Bedeutungen kommen deiner Meinung nach in Frage?

Comment: Mich interessiert, ob die Wendungen Synonyme sind und warum das so ist(wenn das der Fall ist), weil verwenden und verschwenden nichts miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: Ich kann keinen inhaltlichen Unterschied feststellen. Ob eine Bedeutungsnuance beabsichtigt ist, kann letztlich nur der Autor beantworten. Ich habe den Verdacht, dass der Autor die bekannte Redewendung unbeabsichtigt variiert hat. Oder sie war ihm zu abgegriffen.

Comment: Es gibt einen Unterschied in der Wertigkeit: Verschwenden = nutzlos, wertlos. Verwenden = sinnvoll benutzen.

Comment: ... und darum liegt es nahe, zu vermuten, dass der Autor hier aus dem üblichen "verschwenden" absichtlich "verwenden" gemacht hat, denn er will ja offenbar nahelegen, dass es sinnvoll ist, ans Alter zu denken und dafür finanzielle Vorkehrungen zu treffen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Nein, er berichtet ja darüber, was die Jugendlichen bekennen und kein eigenes Bekenntnis.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich halte "verwenden" für eine neutrale Darstellung, nicht für eine positiv wertende. Ansonsten Zustimmung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein, die Redewendung hat nicht die gleiche Bedeutung. "*Gedanken auf etwas verschwenden*" wird im allgemeine in einer negativen Konstruktion verwendet. Also beispielsweise

> Da hab ich bisher keine Gedanken drauf verschwendet.
>
> Da würde ich keine Gedanken drauf verschwenden.

Sehr selten könnte wohl jemand wirklich behaupten, unnötigerweise an etwas gedacht zu haben z.B.

> Heute habe ich wieder Gedanken an meinen Exfreund verschwendet

Das ist aber sehr expressiv und eher ungewöhnlich und wäre schon eher in überstrukturierten Texten zu finden. Z.B. könnte man auch die Idee des "*Verschwendens von Gedanken*" angreifen und seinen Internet Blog "*Gedankenverschwenderei*" nennen.

"*Gedanken verwenden*" dagegen, auch wenn es sehr ähnlich klingt, hat eine ganz andere Bedeutung und ist durchaus in Texten zu finden. Es hat eine sehr überdachte und theoretisch Bedeutung, die ins Konstruktive geht. Also wenn man Gedanken auf etwas verwendet, dann tut man noch nicht wirklich was, aber man hat durchaus die Absicht dort etwas zu investieren. Es schwingt eine gewisse sorgfältige Abwägung in dieser Konstruktion mit.

Answer (score -1):

*Verschwenden* impliziert eine Nutzlosigkeit, die im Hinblick auf Altersversorgung fraglos völlig fehl am Platz ist. Da man beim flüchtigen Lesen die ungewöhnliche Formulierung leicht überliest, gibt es viele griffigere Wendungen, wie:

> ... sich derzeit nicht mit Altersversorgung auseinanderzusetzen/ zu beschäftigen

Comment: "keinen Gedanken verschwenden" wird ja oft ironisch in solchen Fällen verwendet, wo es an sich höchst angebracht wäre, einem Punkt Aufmerksamkeit zu schenken, Vielleicht schien dem Autor beim Thema Altersvorsorge Ironie fehl am Platz.

Comment: @RHa Vielleicht hat er sich aber auch nur in der Schublade vergriffen und das lautähnliche "verwenden" kurzerhand zum Idiom erhoben.

Comment: Das ist nicht fraglos fehl am Platze, sei es, weil das System der Altersvorsorge kollabiert, sei es, weil die Jugendlichen vorher sterben, und sie deshalb nie erleben werden.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich kann im Beispielsatz keine Einschränkung auf die gesetzliche Altersversorgung erkennen und bin deshalb von jeglicher Form ausgegangen.

Comment: Dann korrigiere meinen Satz gedanklich zu "weil Altersversorgungssysteme kollabieren". Mehr solche Systeme können ja nur mehr Möglichkeiten eröffnen, nicht weniger, unterminieren die Fraglosigkeiten also mehr, nicht weniger. Der fehlende Kontext eröffnet der Phantasie dabei jeden gewünschten Raum, räumlich, zeitlich, milieumäßig, vom Genre her, ...